# Did conda install still getting module could not be found for jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, seaborn, python-import

I have installed sea born using **conda install seaborn** 
which was successfully installed, able to see the package in C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

But when I try importing in jupyter lab i get the following error:

**Error Log:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6d7706a59841> in <module>
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
----> 5 import seaborn as sns

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py in <module>
      4 
      5 # Import seaborn objects
----> 6 from .rcmod import *
      7 from .utils import *
      8 from .palettes import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py in <module>
      3 import functools
      4 import matplotlib as mpl
----> 5 from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
      6 
      7 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py in <module>
     10 from .external.six.moves import range
     11 
---> 12 from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
     13 from .colors import xkcd_rgb, crayons
     14 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py in <module>
      5 
      6 import numpy as np
----> 7 from scipy import stats
      8 import pandas as pd
      9 import matplotlib as mpl

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>
    343 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    344 
--> 345 from .stats import *
    346 from .distributions import *
    347 from .morestats import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>
    167 from scipy._lib.six import callable, string_types
    168 from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion
--> 169 import scipy.special as special
    170 import scipy.linalg as linalg
    171 from . import distributions

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py in <module>
    638 from .sf_error import SpecialFunctionWarning, SpecialFunctionError
    639 
--> 640 from ._ufuncs import *
    641 
    642 from .basic import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Tried using pip too:

```
(base) E:\data_science_project\TELECOM CUSTOMER CHURN>pip install Seaborn
Requirement already satisfied: Seaborn in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.3 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Seaborn) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=1.4.3 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Seaborn) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.15.2 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Seaborn) (0.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14.0 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Seaborn) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.4.3->Seaborn) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.4.3->Seaborn) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.4.3->Seaborn) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.4.3->Seaborn) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.15.2->Seaborn) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib>=1.4.3->Seaborn) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib>=1.4.3->Seaborn) (41.4.0)
```

other details:

**jupyter kernelspec list:**

```
python3  C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

**sys.executable:**

```
'C:\\Users\\admin\\Anaconda3\\python.exe'
```

**sys.path:**

```
['C:\\Users\\admin\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Anaconda3',
 '',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\.ipython']
```

Have tried restarting kernel,jupylab many times,

I am getting two kernels options:

**1. Python 3

 2. Python[conda env:root]**

I have tried with both n numbers of times

**kernel.json file**:(C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\kernels\python3)

```
{
 "argv": [
  "C:\\Users\\admin\\Anaconda3\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Have tried deleting kernel file also but nothing fixed my issue,

Please help if have any idea , Thanks

Comment: Try making a new environment and import seaborn: 1. `conda create -n sns_test seaborn` 2. `conda activate sns_test`. 3. `python -c "import seaborn"`. If that works, I would just continute to install the packages you need in the new env and get rid of the old one.

Comment: Your `scipy` package is broken, i.e., it can't find a required shared library. This can happen for many reasons and is hard to diagnose. You could try force reinstalling `scipy` (`conda install --force-reinstall scipy`). Or if you can figure out the library (the error message leaves out the actual DLL it was looking for), reinstall that.